# Is there any way of knowing if it's day or night before joining the server?

Tags: dayz-2012

My computer takes a while to load *DayZ*. My computer can also barely *run DayZ*.

Whenever I spend five minutes joining a server, I am immediately disappointed when it is pitch black. Due to my insufficient graphics capabilities, no adjusting of settings will allow me to see any better at night. This, unfortunately, makes the game entirely unplayable for me (I already have fairly poor vision).

I realize that this is just inclusive of the difficulty and realism of the game, but:

**Is there any way to tell the current server time of day (or night) before I load?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The servers show day or night depending on the actual, real-world time of the server.

Many DayZ servers show the timezone (as an offset from [GMT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time)/UTC) that server is set for.  For example, the server `DayZ - US #00 (1.7.2.3/95251) [REC][GMT-5]` is located in GMT-5, whose current time can be found [here](http://www.timegenie.com/utc.time/UTC-5).  At the time of this writing, it's 10:30PM there, so that server will have night.

If the server does not display the timezone in the server-name, the best you can do is join servers located in a part of the world that currently has daylight.  A lot of them change the timezone, though, so this method is not fool-proof.

Comment: You can also download a "launcher" program like DayzCommander http://www.dayzcommander.com/ , which shows the time of the server (though I've found it to be incorrect a very few times).