# How can I find a daytime server in Dayz Standalone?

Tags: dayz-standalone

I've spent about 2 hours logging in and out of servers all around the world to find one with daytime. Some say in their descriptions that they are 24/7 daylight but they are not. Has this feature not been implemented yet or are all servers on the same GMT time ?

Any clue on how to find them with their host list filter?

Comment: Although this earlier Arqade topic doesn't directly answer your question (it's not about the host list filter for 24/7 daylight servers), it may help since it gives advice for finding servers that are currently having daytime: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/78357/is-there-any-way-of-knowing-if-its-day-or-night-before-joining-the-server

Answer (score 1):

I am not a server administrator, all the information about servers is to my best knowledge.

Servers don't have an explicit setting to keep them at daytime, but it seems like you can define the time a server starts at after a restart.

> Server operators MAY frequently restart their rented instances in order to keep the time at a certain point..

[(Source)](http://forums.dayzgame.com/index.php?/topic/158966-dayz-standalone-server-hosting-rules-server-reporting/)

This explains why you currently can't search for these servers using a specific filter.

You can however filter for some strings in the host filter. (ommit quotes)
"24/7 day"
"daytime"
"daylight"

This isn't a guarantee for daylight servers. Servers currently on nighttime are usually low populated, so this is another thing to look out for.

Answer (score 1):

In the in game server browser you can see the current server time. I believe it becomes light around 0900 and dark around 1800, so pick one between these hours.

Quick note that the server time is in 24hr time, so 0100 is 1am, not 1pm, I have been fooled by this a couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

Baarn already sayd that "24/7 day", "daytime" and "daylight" are common names for such servers.

You can search in the serverbrowser or on [gametracker.com](https://www.gametracker.com/search/dayz/).

[image]